# Error on load of Lisp-Stat into Franz ACL

Tags: xlispstat

I was hopeful that I could load Lisp-Stat into the commercial common lisp by Franz: Allegro Common Lisp 10.1, but I do get an error message. Error: System "sb-cltl2" not found.

So, looks like there is a dependency on SBCL. Is there a way to work around this?

Sorry, there isn't much detail from the quicklisp quickload call. I had to remove details so that stackoverflow would stop insisting that my question is spam.

--John

Answer (score 0):

That was fixed for CCL in the repo, but not for ACL. Also note that Lisp-Stat won't load into the free version of ACL because of heap size restrictions (at least version 10 wouldn't).  I don't have a commercial license any longer, but the fix is a one-liner you can try.

Would you please report this as an issue at https://github.com/Lisp-Stat/data-frame/issues ?

Comment: As suggested, I reported the issue on github. Thanks for the answer.